# How can I get output binaries after c++ build

Tags: c#, c++, msbuild, native

I'm trying to get the output binaries after c++ build (compilation + linking) .

To get output binaries after c# build via msbuild, we can get the result using the var `ReferenceCopyLocalPaths`. So I need to make the same behaviour using c++ build.

So is there any same variable or other way to get back the binaries files when building vcxproj (c++ project).

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking - a single vcxproj usually has only one output binary and that should be the `TargetPath` property. There's even an msbuild target `GetTargetPath` to get it if needed.

Comment: @stijn not realy just one binary and if the c++ project depend on some dll or some content or other projects. the binary will not be only one file. So their is any property which contain all the output files ?

Comment: When one c++ project depends on another, say a dll project, then this is resolved at link time by linking with the import library or at runtime, but afaik there's no system like for c# where you set 'copy local' and then the referenes are copied to the project's output directory (or I don't know about it, please correct me if I'm wrong). As such, the c++ project does not really know where it's dependencies are, let alone there's a property containing all of them. Please edit your question and provide some explanation about your project's structure (which output files are where etc)